# JQGrid is it possible to remove paging when searching?

Tags: jquery, css, jqgrid

Is there an easy way to disable paging when searching in a JQGrid?
When a user searches I want to display all of the search results on one page.

Basically I want `rowNum: 10000` and the pager disabled but only when a user searches.

**Edit:** Got this to work with something like:

```
  beforeRequest: function () {
                            if (jQuery("#ClientPickerGrid").getGridParam('search') == true) {                                 
                                jQuery("#ClientPickerGrid").setGridParam({ rowNum: 10000 })
                            }
```

Comment: if it's possible to put your piece of target code into jsfiddle, you can get an answer as soon as possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usage of `rowNum: -1` is not supported by jqGrid especially if you use local datatype or `loadonce: true` option. You should use and large enough value like `rowNum: 1000` or `rowNum: 10000`.

**UPDATED**: The solution can depend on the `datatype` which you use and on the value of the `loadonce` parameter. Moreover you can use some events existing in searching. So if you write about searching you should always write which one from the [searching](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3ajqgriddocs#searching) you use.

If no other information is known you can use `beforeRequest` event to test whether `search` parameter of jqGrid is set to `true`. In the case you can temporary change the value of `rowNum` and restore it's original value in `loadComplete`. If you send the request to the server (if you use `datatype: 'json'` or `datatype: 'xml'`) it can be important to change the `rows` value sent to the server. You can do this inside of `serializeGridData` event handler. Inside of `serializeGridData` the `search` will be seen in the posted data as `_search`.

Comment: thanks, got this to work just setting the rowNum in beforeRequest